# Find a Value with the row number and store it into a variable

Tags: r, object, find, match

I am new in R and probably this is an easy question:

I have the following vector:

`P <- c(23,45,98)`

These values represent the numbers of rows

Now, I have a table with only one column and I would like to obtain the values on each row from the previous vector and return it into 3 different objects (Variables).

e.g. The row #23 has the value `P05.14` and for this first value of the vector "P" I want to create a variable or object like: `A = P05.14`. The same with the other two values of that vector.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you work with characters instead of numbers?

Comment: Are you sure that you mean `P <- c("23, 45, 98")` and not `P <- c(23, 45, 98)`?

Comment: I made a mistake, it is without " "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have the three values, just do it manually:

```
A <- dat[23,]
B <- dat[45,]
C <- dat[98,]
```

For more values, you can assign them in a loop:

```
for(value in P){
  assign(paste0("A",value), as.character(dat[value,]))
}
```

I should note that in a situation such as this, it would be best to use a list, and not litter the workspace with variable. But to each their own. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Joel. The only problem in doing it manually is that those values are always changing and I would have to change the names as well. I would like to change only the "P"

Comment: Is it always three values in P?

Comment: No, could be from 1 to any, 3 was just an example.

Comment: What are the requirements on the variable names?

Comment: They are digital addresses. From P01.00 to P01.19 and the same from P01 to P144

Comment: I mean the variables you wish to create

Comment: Ahh sorry, no they should be simple objects. Names that I can call later, maybe to place it into a cell. Characters. Does this answer your question?

Comment: P.S. If I answered your question, please accept it as an answer

Comment: Thank Joel, It does work but I have a final question: Each variable doesnt show only the name but also all the levels from where is coming from. it shows:

Comment: > A289
[1] P 15.08
2880 Levels: P 01.00 P 01.01 P 01.02 P 01.03 P 01.04 P 01.05 P 01.06 P 01.07 P 01.08 P 01.09 P 01.10 ... P 99.19